# Direction ratios of vectors

Tags: vectors

Why do vectors have infinite direction ratios though they have unique direction cosine .My textbook has just stated these points but not explained them nor my teacher so I am bit confused at this part.My textbook is limited to 3D strictly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction cosine is computed by dividing two terms, which gives a fixed quantity. The direction ratio is a ratio given by one term per dimension, without performing any division; multiplying by a nonzero constant gives a different list of terms but an equivalent ratio.

The situation is akin to the following. There are infinitely many ways to write the ratio $2:1$: you can write $4:2$, $6:3$, $108:54$, etc. However, there is only one unique *quotient* $\frac{2}{1} = \frac{4}{2} = \frac{6}{3} = \frac{108}{54} = 2$

Comment: Then why does the unit vector of a position vector gives us direction ratio if there are infinite ratios?

Comment: The unit vector gives us _one_ way to write the ratio.  E.g., if the unit vector is $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{-1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt2}{2})$, we can write the ratio as $\frac{1}{2}: \frac{-1}{2} : \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$. We can also write it as $1: -1 : \sqrt2$ or infinitely other ways

Comment: So basically  there are infinite between direction cosine and ratio and also the unit vector gives us just one values of these ratio

Comment: Does this also mean parallel vectors will have same direction ratio and cosine

Comment: They will. Since direction ratio and cosine are designed to measure direction, and parallel vectors have the same direction, this should be expected.

Comment: According to me,Direction ratios tell us the angle that the position vector makes with the axes.How does direction ratio tell us about direction.....is it because it is related to unit vector?

Comment: @HydrousCaperilla If we know the angles with the axes, we can fix the direction. Not sure what notion of "direction" you have in mind. One way of specifying a direction is by a unit vector -- in this case, yes, the relation to unit vector here expresses the fixing of the direction.

Comment: So to vectors with same direction the direction ratio gets fixed and hence they have same ratios and cosine...right?

Comment: @HydrousCaperilla They will.

Comment: thanks for your help.Real life saver for me